# Why is one of my urls not being scraped when part of a list and is scraped with done alone?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have a list of 2600+ urls i need to scrape, but during development of the spider, im working with only 115, everytime i run the spider, i get mixed results.. (without changing code) There is 1 url that when i crawl alone works and returns as expected. But when i run it within the list of 115 the crawler throws a exception

Im looking for a specific tag to grab a alphanumeric list of characters.. and in most cases, that is always available in a javascript tag and this works great for most of the URLS, but then it doesnt, so i have a mix of 2 look up methods to try and find different parts of the information i need..

1. using soup im pulling all the tags with the data i want and then looping thru to get the text i need..
2. using soup i find the javascript tag and parse thru it looking for the 1 key value i need and that is not always 100%

The url im having on and off results with is this one
    https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/coleman-2-burner-propane-camp-stove-15colu2brnrstvxxxcac/15colu2brnrstvxxxcac?

What setting can i enable or change to allow more load time for the page before trying to scrape it?

Here is what i have enabled and configured in my settings.py file

```
# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 2
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 20
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False
```

Im looking for and expecting the "partnumber" and instead getting an error as below:

```
jvscript = soup.select_one('#skuDescriptivattribute').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Maybe you are getting detected as a bot, or overloading the web server, and you are getting a false or incomplete response? Have you tried saving on disk the body of that specific response, to see what it looks like?

Comment: the thing is that i have the above settings which i would have hoped would help keep my attempts to a minimum.And if i scrape the url alone it works 100% of the time.. only when its part of the list does it fail  Where in the above autothrottle settings would i insure that im only hitting the server every few seconds? i dont want to send 100 requests at a time.. i want to split those up into maybe 5 or 10 every few seconds..

Comment: `AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY` ensures that you only send requests one at a time, but delay is based on response time. You can decrease its value (e.g. to `0.5` or `0.2`) to increase the delay between requests or not use AUTOTHROTTLE and instead go with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and related settings.